# React Router sub-route call a different parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Version 4 of React Router**

I have a sub-route setup:`/profile/agree` and on that sub-route I want a `<Link>` tag to go to `/team`.

It's setup right now so the parent page has:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    <Route path="/team" component={Team} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And the profile component has it's own routing:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/profile" component={General} />
    <Route path="/profile/hotel" component={Hotel} />
    <Route path="/profile/release" component={Release} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Whether this is right or not, I'm not sure since none of the docs seem to explain this type of scenario, but it made sense to me.  Anyway when that "Release" component has a simple link, it doesn't seem to navigate properly and just shows a blank page:

```
<a href="/team">Somehow</a> {/* << This works but refreshes the whole page */}
<Link to="/team">Of Course</Link> {/* << This just shows empty profile page /*}
```

I thought maybe the sub-router can only look up as high as itself, so perhaps:

```
<Link to="../team">Of Course</Link>
```

But that did the same thing.  It seems to remain on the "profile" main route.  How does one navigate to a different parent route?

Comment: Have you seen this in the documentation? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

Comment: Yes @taylorc93 but it seems a bit confusing.  The idea that you would have to create some sort of "route with subroutes" component seems odd.  I'll try and write what they have and look closer to understand what/why the do it that way. Example: why do they have a JSON definition of the routes instead of just nesting elements?  I also wanted each route to handle it's own routing (not one know-it-all)... is that a strange thing?  I'm thinking similar to Router patterns of ExpressJS.  Each route doesn't care what the root is, they just add more to wherever they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured out the simple error I had.  The fact that Profile had `<Router>` in it!

Doing this worked in Profile (simply removed Router tag):

```
  <Switch>
   <Route exact path="/profile" component={General} />
   <Route path="/profile/hotel" component={Hotel} />
   <Route path="/profile/release" component={Release} />
 </Switch>
```

This gives me what I think makes the most sense.  Each "scene" is responsible for it's own routing.  The only downside is it still needs `/profile`, although I could probably get crafty and send the "root" as a property to the scenes.